# Webapp deploy workflow and security issues

Tags: git, security, deployment

I'm currently developing a web app.
I need now to deploy it on the server where it should run.

I've created three different branches on my git repository: development, staging and production. I've merged my developmnet branch with staging, tested it, and then merged it on my production branch.

My question are:
**Is there a way to checkout on the server only the production branch?** I've set up a deploy key on the server but if i just git clone, the server will clone all the branches. It would be nice if I can send to the server only the commits merged on the production branch.

**Is there a way to avoid people having access to the server to checkout different branches?** Actually, there is somebody else having access to the server I'm working on. So I want to protect my web app environment. Any suggestion?

Comment: For the 1st question, `git clone -b <branch> --single-branch` clones the specific branch only. As to the 2nd, are you using the same username to access to the server?

Comment: @ElpieKay thank you for your answer. I have found that command on the documentation but I wasn't sure it was the correct workflow. For the 2nd question yes. There is only one user on the server. Would you suggest to create a second user in which I manage my web app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing a login (especially with someone you apparently don't trust) then there is absolutely nothing you can do with git to make the situation secure.  Period.

First of all, there are *much worse* things they can do to your webapp then switch it to a version you weren't ready to release.

But ok, for the exercise, let's suppose for some reason the only malicious thing they would possibly be motivated to do is to release a feature prematurely.  So you try the `--single-branch` idea from the comments.

But that is not a security feature.  It doesn't *prevent* someone fetching other branches, it just makes it so the default behaviors only fetch that one branch.  So now it's a question of how you secure your remote.  Do you type in a password every time you need to access the remote?  If not, then the other user (who is, after all, logged in under the same account as you) can just fetch whatever they want.

So if you configure git to not use ssh, and not store your password, and literally require you to manually log in for every fetch/pull; *and* you do a `--single-branch` clone (and assuming this other guy doesn't have some other way to access the remote repo; really this becomes a question of how/where your remote is hosted), then they won't have access to future versions of the app.  They will still have access to every past version that led up to the current production version, including ones that were never intended for production release; because `single-branch` still clones full history.  So lets say your `production` branch never receives changes other than by merging from the staging branch.  You have

```
D1 -- D2 -- D3 -- D4 -- D5 -- D6 -- D7 -- D8 -- D9 <--(dev)
        \           \                 \     \
         S1 -------- S2 -------------- S3 -- S4 <--(staging)
                       \                 \
                        P1 -------------- P2 <--(production)
```

Now, cloning `--single-branch --branch production` includes not only `P1` and `P2`, but also `S1` through `S3` and `D1` through `D7` - because they are all "reachable" (via parent pointers) from the `production` branch.

So all of those versions are still locally present and available.  You could use a feature called "shallow cloning" (look up the `--depth` option of the `clone` command) to limit that problem (so long as you use it consistently) - but of course still *every* production version will be locally available.  The only way to ensure that the only local version is the correct version would be to blow away the repo and re-clone a single-commit shallow history of the production branch.  But at this point, you're jumping through enough hoops to shoehorn your deployment needs into git, that you might as well use a real deployment tool instead.

(Actually, using git as a deployment tool is almost always a bad idea IMO, but for some reason it remains popular.)

And all of that is just to prevent them from doing something they probably weren't going to do anyway - change the version of your web app - while they still have the ability to do things like manually edit your running version to include malware, or delete files to disable your app, or any number of things that should be bigger concerns with sharing a login.

Comment: Hi Mark and thank you a lot for your answer. You gave me a lot of information to think about. Actually, another big concern I have is related, as you said, to the fact that who has access to the server can modify and delete files as well as include malwares. Said that, the first thing I should do is to create another user on the server which cannot be accessed from people I don't trust, am I right? And I will install my app on that user in order to avoid other users to access my files. This is my first approach so any suggestion will be really appreciated. I really want to make a secure app!